# Spurrious warning when using mathdesign for Adobe Garamond Pro in conjunction with fontspec

Tags: luatex, fontspec, mathdesign

I am using lualatex to typeset documents with Adobe Garamond Pro, using the mathdesign package with the "adobe-garamond" option for the math fonts. However, this nets me a warning upon loading fontspec,

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `EU2/lmr/sb/n' undefined
(Font) using `EU2/lmr/m/n' instead on input line 356.
```

This warning remains whether I load a font with fontspec or not. It has no relevance whatsoever to the output: even if the final document has no Latin Modern at all, it is displayed! It is specific to the "adobe-garamond" option: if I were to use mathdesign with another font option, it would disappear.

Here is a mwe:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage[adobe-garamond]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec} 
%\setmainfont{whatever!}

\begin{document}
This is a test.
\end{document}
```

What is the source of this behavior? Is there a way to cleanly remove the warning, or at least silence it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mathdesign` module for `adobe-garamond` sets

```
\renewcommand{\bfdefault}{sb}
```

but of course you don't need it in case the text fonts are overridden with `fontspec`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[adobe-garamond]{mathdesign}
\renewcommand{\bfdefault}{bx}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}

\begin{document}
This is a test.
\end{document}
```